# What wrong with my Python code to check the triangular number?

Tags: python-2.7, triangular

```
def Triangular(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        T = i*(i+1)/2
        arr.append(T)
    if n == any(arr):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

All test cases are in False. Please show me what I was wrong

Comment: what are the test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any()` returns a boolean, True or False. you are comparing it to `n`, an integer. Change the line to

```
if n in arr:
```

Or even better yet you can just delete the whole `if..else` statement and replace it with simply:

```
return n in arr
```

edit: you can even avoid creating an array in the first place like this:

```
def Triangular(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        if i*(i+1)/2 == n:
            return True
    return False
```

This immediately returns True when it finds that `n` is triangular. If it gets to the end of the list and doesn't find any, it returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what is the time complexity for this solution ?

Comment: This fails on `1` which technically is triangular.

Answer (score 1):

Try this lambda:

```
Triangular = lambda x: (0.5 * ((8 * x + 1) ** 0.5 - 1)).is_integer()
```

Here's how it works:

1. Multiply `n` by 8 and subtract 1
2. Find the square root of that number
3. Subtract it by 1 and divide it by 2
4. Remove the decimal part of the number
5. If the resulting number is greater than 0, it is triangular

You can also use this lambda from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122087/is-this-number-triangular#answer-122092) to check if the number is Triangular:

```
Triangular = lambda n:(8*n+1)**.5%1>0
```

Comment: As a one liner `is_triangular = lambda x: (0.5 * ((8 * x + 1) ** 0.5 - 1)).is_integer()`